# Visual Studio 2015: is a set of const pointers allowed?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, visual-studio-2015, containers

We will be upgrading to VS2015 soon, and I found this in the breaking changes list:

> const elements
>
> The C++ standard has always forbidden containers of const elements
>   (such as vector or set). Visual C++ 2013 and earlier
>   accepted such containers. In the current version, such containers fail
>   to compile.

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx)

I was wondering if anyone knows if this also applies to a set.
I know a map can still contain const pointers as keys, since they are const anyway.

An example:

```
std::set<const QObject*>
```

Can I still do this? I would think not, according to the post on the site of Microsoft.

Comment: `const T*` and `T* const` not the same thing.

Comment: The quote literally says that it applies to set. However, your code doesn't have much to do with the quote so you're safe :)

Comment: The confusion is reinforced by the nobly-intended-but-misleading style that omits the space before the asterisk (or ampersand on a reference).  Writing `const QObject*` visually suggests that the `*` binds to QObject tighter than the `const` does.  Moving the `const` doesn't help: `QObject const*`.  It's like writing `return a * x+b * y;`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`const QObject*` is a pointer **to a** `const QObject`. The pointer itself is still modifiable. `const QObject* const` would make the pointer itself `const`.

Since the Microsoft article talks about `const` objects, which `const QObject*` is **not**, your example is fine.

Answer (score 4):

> I know a map can still contain const pointers as keys, since they are const anyway.

`std::set<T* const>` has always been invalid, and `std::map<int* const, int* const> s;` has always been valid. The reason is because the allocator for `std::set` is `std::allocator<Key>`, whereas the allocator for `std::map` is `std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>`. By definition, a `std::allocator<const T>` is ill-formed. If you want the `map` code to fail, you'll have to specify a custom allocator like this:

```
int i = 42;
int* const j = &i;
std::map<int* const, int* const,
    std::allocator<const std::pair<int* const, int* const>>> s{{j, j}};
```